# Linq множественный выбор (если не содержит)

Tags: c#, linq

Вот выборка по 2 условиям

```
using (AccidentContext db = new AccidentContext())
{
    var kinds = new[] { "Delete", "Change" };
    var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => kinds.Contains(p.Kind));
    foreach (var VARIABLE in accidents)
    {
        AccidentList.Add(VARIABLE);
    }
}
```

А как сделать такую же выборку которая выбирает все другие варианты исключая Delete и Change?

Comment: `db.Accidents.Where(p => !kinds.Contains(p.Kind));` ?

Comment: @trydex сделай в виде ответа. Я тебе плюс поставлю

Comment: Задумайтесь над тем, что, может быть, стоит сделать Kind типа `enum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете просто развернуть условие:

```
db.Accidents.Where(p => !kinds.Contains(p.Kind));
```

Или воспользоваться `Except`:

```
var kinds = new[] { "Delete", "Change" };
var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => kinds.Contains(p.Kind));
var accidentsExceptDeleteAndChange = db.Accidents.Except(accidents);
```